# Output to a file after running Python script line by line and spaces between columns

Tags: python, output

I am trying to run a python script which reads the contents of the input file and need to     display in a line by line ( row by row) format in the output file.

```
                     Script is as below:
                  ==============================

                #!/usr/bin/python
                 # Usage : python loop_test1.py /home/cdn/test1.in /home/cdn/test11.out
                   from user_agents import parse
                    import sys,getopt
                         import csv
                 myopts, args = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:],"i:o:")
                   # open file

                    f = open (sys.argv[1],"r")
                     #sys.stdout = open(sys.argv[2], "w")
                     #sys.stdout=open(sys.argv[2],"w")
                          results= (user_agent.browser,user_agent.browser.family,user_agent.browser.version,user_agent.browser.version_string)
                     c = csv.writer(open(sys.argv[2],"wb"), delimiter="|")
                       c.writerows(results)
                      #f1.write("|".join(fields))
                     #Read whole file into data
                     data = f.readline()


                       # Print it 
                        #line = 0
                       for line in iter(f):
                      # print line
                       #line + = 1  

                    user_agent = parse(line)
                  print user_agent.browser  # returns Browser(family=u'Mobile  Safari',    version=(5, 1), version_string='5.1')
                print user_agent.browser.family,"|"  # returns 'Mobile Safari'
                print user_agent.browser.version # returns (5, 1)
               print user_agent.browser.version_string   # returns '5.1'
                    # Accessing user agent's operating system properties
             print user_agent.os  # returns OperatingSystem(family=u'iOS', version=(5,   1), version_string='5.1')
              print user_agent.os.family  # returns 'iOS'
              print user_agent.os.version  # returns (5, 1)
              print user_agent.os.version_string  # returns '5.1'

            # Accessing user agent's device properties
             print user_agent.device  # returns Device(family='iPhone')
             print user_agent.device.family  # returns 'iPhone'
                print user_agent.is_mobile # returns True
                print user_agent.is_tablet # returns False
               print user_agent.is_touch_capable # returns False
               print user_agent.is_pc # returns False
               print user_agent.is_bot # returns False

              # Close the file
                f.close()
```

## I get this error :

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "loop_test1.py", line 11, in 
    results=(user_agent.browser,user_agent.browser.family,user_agent.browser.version,user_agent.browser.version_string)
NameError: name 'user_agent' is not defined

Could you guys kindly help me out with this ?

Answer (score 0):

you seem to import from user_agents (with a "s")but later you use user_agent.

Importing parse and none of the rest seems a little odd. Might as well use user_agents.parse() for that to have one style.

Also I hope the indentation is different in your script than what you posted :)

Comment: changed it..now I get the error : [cdn@verticacdn1 ~]$ python loop_test1.py /home/cdn/test1.in /home/cdn/test11.out
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "loop_test1.py", line 3, in <module>
    from user_agent import parse
ImportError: No module named user_agent

Comment: what is user_agent ? a file ? a library that you installed ? I was actually thinking of changing the calls to user_agents and not changing the import since the import seems to have been correct. For example change user_agent.browser to user_agents.browser